# EBAY - Sending a file via http post?

Tags: ebay-lms

I've a file I want to send to the ebay system to support the LMS. 
All the samples I've found include the use of the API, but the environment I'm working in doesn't have the ability to use it (the api).

So I'm forced to send the file with an HTTP post.  But the doc's seem lacking.

Has anyone constructed/found an example of a HTTP post that will send a given file.

EDIT:
Oh.. what I see in the samples I have found is an area that seems it's supposed to have the data, but in the sample, there's nothing I'd consider real data.

Comment: Hi I'm looking at the same thing at the moment - maybe we could compare notes?

Comment: @RichardW1001 did you ever get this working?

Comment: sorry, can't even remember - been too long - I'd also guess the API/SDKs have probably changed by now as well

Comment: The API's remain the same. There are new SDK's but nothing for ruby/rails

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the file transfer service or the bulk upload service?  Don't you just generate an xml document and post the url like in this example:
http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/file-transfer/CallRef/uploadFile.html#Samples

Comment: didn't look at the date on this post.